# hoverIntent conditional

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

So I'm trying to use [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to control the delayed hover on some images.  The images will enlarge when hovered momentarily.  It's conditional, though, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  If it's on the left hand side of the screen, it will enlarge like normal, but if it's on the right hand side of the screen, it moves to the left as well.

```
$(".card").live('click', function () {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var pos = offset.left;

        if (windowWidth - pos < 500) {      
            var config = {
                over: alert(id+" right"),
                timeout: 500,
                out: alert('out'),
                sensitivity: 7,
                interval: 500
            }
        $(this).hoverIntent( config )           
        }

        else (pos < 500) {
            var config = {
                over: alert(id+" left"),
                timeout: 500, 
                out: alert('out'),
                sensitivity: 7,
                interval: 500
            }
            $(this).hoverIntent( config )
        }
})
```

Now, I'd really like this to work without the `.live('click')` function (which is only a click for testing purposes), but I don't know how else to assign my variables to what's being moused over (to locate the image).

Ideally, I'd like to do a `.live('hoverIntent')`, but that doesn't work, or I'm just not sure how to pull it off.

Something tells me I have the whole thing botched.  http://magic.cardbinder.com/ to test.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

### Delegate the click and ditch the intent plugin

If you want to delegate the event use $.on on the body with selectors to pin them to the .card elements.

```
$("body").on("click", ".card", function(){
    //event script here
});
```

As for the rest of your script I think you might want something a little more robust.

First check how far off the screen the image is. Screen widths will vary so knocking it back on the screen 500px won't cut it if a) the image is only off by 10px, b) the image more than 500px off screen.

Next you will need to rethink the intent plugin; is it really necessarily? writing your own would be better:

```
var tOut;

$("body").on("mouseover", ".card", function(){
    clearTimeout(tOut);
    tOut = setTimeout(function(){
        //enlarge!
    }, 300);
});
```

This is just a start but it should be a helpful hand in the right direction

Comment: $(document).on("click", ".card", function () {
   windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var offset = $(this).offset();
   var pos = offset.left;
    
   if (windowWidth - pos < 340) {
    alert(id+" right") 
   }
   else if (pos < 260) {
    over: alert(id+" left")
   }
   else {
    alert(id+" middle")
   }
  })